# How to catch exception of <init> block for Android activity?

Tags: java, android, exception, oncreate

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textbox);

    //rest of code.........
```

Above code generates the following exception,

```
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.Window.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
    at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:2090)
    at com.example.kuldeep.myapplication.MainActivity.<init> (MainActivity.java:24)
```

When I debugged this, I come to know that this code is executed even before the onCreate() method. 
How is this possible? and How to catch this type of exceptions?

Comment: Probably best to move the initialization to the `onCreate` method. How is it possible that it is called before? Because the code is executed when constructing the object, which has to be done before `onCreate` can even be called.

Comment: in simple words, you should move this code to your onCreate() block.

Answer (score 1):

> How is this possible?

Because that is what you wrote. Field initializers (e.g., `(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textbox)`) are executed when the instance of the activity is created.

> How to catch this type of exceptions?

You don't. Instead, you avoid the exception. In general, do not call methods that you inherit from `Activity` from a field initializer. More specifically, you cannot find a widget until the widget exists, and that will not occur until `setContentView()` is called (or you otherwise set up the UI of this activity).